# Adding dynamic rows using Ext.ux.form.plugin.HtmlEditor

Tags: extjs4

I have created a html table in html editor .Now i want to add dynamic rows to the table .I tried it using the Ext.ux.form.HtmlTableEditor plugin.But Iam not sure how to use this plugin.Is there any solution to this?